# Getting XML with Grails REST plugin

Tags: xml, rest, grails

I'm having trouble working with the REST plugin in grails. Specifically I am trying to convert xml from a get request into a Map in a controller.

The data source I am trying to get data from returns XML that looks like this (this is shortened for simplicity):

```
<process id="345">
    <correctedBy>Joanne W.</correctedBy>
    <editBy>Joanne W.</editBy>
    <editDate>2009-12-23 00:00:00.0 EST</editDate>
    <produceBy>Stephen</produceBy>
    <produceDate>2010-01-14 00:00:00.0 EST</produceDate>
</process>
```

In my controller I have code to make the get request to this service

```
def getRest = {
        def wfRequest
        withHttp(uri: "http://myurl:8080") {
               wfRequest = get(path : '/application/controller/' + params.id,
                   requestContentType: XML) { resp, xml ->
                        render xml
                   }
        }
}
```

Ok so far, this will return the data from the xml, but all the tags are gone:

```
Joanne W.Joanne W.2009-12-23 00:00:00.0 ESTStephen2010-01-14 00:00:00.0 EST
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to access the XML that is returned from this request? I'd like to step through each kay value pair in the "process" node of the xml and populate a map that would look like

```
[correctedBy: Joanne W., editBy: Joanne W., editDate: 2009-12-23 00:00:00.0 EST, produceBy: Stephen, produceDate: 2010-01-14 00:00:00.0 EST]
```

I'm finding the rest plugin documentation a little confusing, any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated.

Thanks!

Donald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that when you say render xml it doesn't show the tags.  At this point, XML is an [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) object, so it's just calling the toString().

See [this for more information](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/xml.html).

So since you have an [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper), you just need to use it.

Comment: Ok! I used render just to demonstrate where I am at, as I can't seem to crack into the XML, i wasn't expecting for that to display any XML. I'll check this out right away, i was unfamiliar with this class. Thanks!